# Regex Spliting a String Mid Search-Phrase

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex command to split a string that looks like this:

```
messageList = Regex.Split(content, @"(?=TXT)");
```

This was not specific enough. I actually need to split it where TXT is preceded by a carriage return like so.

```
messageList = Regex.Split(content, @"(?=\r\nTXT)");
```

The problem that I am running into is that I actually need the "\r\n" to be at the end of the previous segment and the "TXT" to be at the beginning of the new segment. Thus, a string like this

```
TXT1\r\nTXT2\r\nTXT3\r\n
```

Should give these results.

```
TXT1\r\n
TXT2\r\n
TXT3\r\n
```

Is there a simple modification I can make to the statement to get this to work, or am I going to have to write a method to parse it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a positive look-behind:

```
messageList = Regex.Split(content, @"(?<=\r\n)(?=TXT)");
```